# Enumerate through UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3

In SpriteKit you are able to enumerate through each node with a specific name. Say I have 10 sprites with the name property set to "foo" I can then run the code below and it will move each "food" node up 5 pixels every time the function is called.

```
 enumerateChildNodesWithName("foo"){node, stop in
        let sprite:SKSpriteNode = node as! SKSpriteNode
        sprite.position.x += 5
 }
```

Now, I would like to do this with UIImageView (if possible).

### Here's my current setup

In my app I have code that runs every second. It is supposed to add a UIImageView using the following code

```
var mView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "swirl"))    
self.view.addSubview(mView)
```

Finally, I have a for loop that doesn't seem to be targeting each specific view. But it should be moving each individual image view in a circle. Currently it only looks like a single image is moving even while I think I've added more image views.

```
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let ind = view as? UIImageView {
        let OrCe:CGPoint = mView.center
        mView.center = CGPoint(x: OrCe.x + sin(tick)*50,
                               y: OrCe.y + cos(tick)*50)
    }
}
```

I feel like what I'm doing is really wrong :( Is it possible for me to do what I am trying to do? I would like to do this so that I do not have to use SpriteKit. I want to try and create graphics at a lower level framework. Can I go lower then this even? How can I most efficiently render these 10 moving images?

Comment: you are changing center of mView itself. It should be view  I guess. check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I assume all the two peaces are consecutive.

```
var mView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "swirl"))    
self.view.addSubview(mView)
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let ind = view as? UIImageView {
        let OrCe:CGPoint = view.center
        view.center = CGPoint(x: OrCe.x + sin(tick)*50,
                               y: OrCe.y + cos(tick)*50)
    }
}
```

If got you correct this should work.

Comment: You have just copied and paste. What's new in it?

Comment: He is talking about the performance and you are solving naming error.

Comment: Sohil, there was a clear bug in the original code. Kai was modifying the wrong object inside the loop, and PrafulD fixed it. Kai also included a question about performance, but the main issue was the bug itself.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon This is stupid. Read the question first before down voting. I am not even saying its new. It just one image which is moving and the image is latest one. as she is moving center of the image which is just added.

Comment: @PrafulD The code that adds a subview is ran every second (and the for loop every 1/60 seconds) so there should be more than just one image. However, when I run the for loop currently it only looks like there is a single image. So I'm wondering if I'm actually adding more than one or if they are all sharing the same properties (because I am not changing the property of a single one correctly with the for loop). Sorry if my question was worded poorly.